# I want to decode to "UTF-8"

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, decode

```
The restoration and rejuvenation of the Willamette Army Base\xe2\x80\x94now the Willamette Reservist Training Center\xe2\x80\x94is complete.  \n \n
```

I need to decode all these to "UTF-8" except "\n".
So i want this output

```
Original :The restoration and rejuvenation of the Willamette Army Base\xe2\x80\x94now the Willamette Reservist Training Center\xe2\x80\x94is complete.  \n \n
Decoded : The restoration and rejuvenation of the Willamette Army Base—now the Willamette Reservist Training Center—is complete.  \n \n
```

Comment: You could eliminate „\n“ with .spltlines() then decode each single element in the list and cocatenate it again if necessary

Comment: "decode to UTF-8" doesn't make sense. Please provide Python code that shows the string you have and the string you want to convert it to, the above isn't sufficient. IOW, extract a [mcve]. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Your input string must be a byte string for decoding to make sense. Assuming that use [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=bytes%20decode#bytes.decode):

```
>>> s = b'The restoration and rejuvenation of the Willamette Army Base\xe2\x80\x94now the Willamette Reservist Training Center\xe2\x80\x94is complete.  \n \n'
>>> type(s)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> s2 = s.decode('utf8')
>>> type(s2)
<class 'str'>
>>> s2
'The restoration and rejuvenation of the Willamette Army Base—now the Willamette Reservist Training Center—is complete.  \n \n'
```

The above shows decoding of a byte string (class `bytes`) to a unicode string (class `str`).

Strip off the trailing new lines with [`rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rstrip#str.rstrip):

```
>>> s2.rstrip()
'The restoration and rejuvenation of the Willamette Army Base—now the Willamette Reservist Training Center—is complete.'
```

If your data is coming from a file or other stream you can decode as you read it by specifying an encoding when you open the file/stream:

```
with open('file.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

This will decode the incoming data from UTF8 and your code only deals with strings. not byte strings. See [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) for details.

Comment: It decodes "\n" as new line too.It will stay as "\n"

Comment: @Yusuf2020: you can't do that. You can only _encode_ to a UTF8 string byte string.

Comment: @Yusuf2020: I've added `rstrip()` to remove those trailing new line characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve a particular [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case as follows:

```
s = 'The restoration and rejuvenation of the Willamette Army Base\xe2\x80\x94now the Willamette Reservist Training Center\xe2\x80\x94is complete.  \n \n'
s.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
```

> ```
> 'The restoration and rejuvenation of the Willamette Army Base—now the Willamette Reservist Training Center—is complete.  \n \n'
> ```